# probability of a subsequence knowing the transition graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I have a population having different moving sequences such as:

- `entry -> B -> C -> D -> exit`
- `entry -> A -> B -> C -> exit`
- `entry -> D -> B -> A -> E -> F -> exit`

The sequence's length is variable and around 20 and there is around 200 different nodes.

From those sequences, I have build the following matrix:

```
+-------+---------+------+-------+
| From  | Current | Next | Count |
+-------+---------+------+-------+
| entry | A       | B    |    12 |
| A     | B       | C    |    18 |
| A     | C       | D    |     1 |
| B     | D       | A    |    21 |
| A     | B       | exit |     3 |
| ...   |         |      |       |
+-------+---------+------+-------+
```

It is a "2-step" graph because the previous node impact the next node's probability. For example the sequence `entry -> A -> B -> A -> B -> exit` is quite unlikely to happen even if P(B | A) and P(B | A) are high because I have P(B | A & B) is low.

This graph was built using a sub population that is well "sampled". Unfortunately, I have some other populations that does not have this "definition". For example, the sequence could be `entry -> B -> E -> exit`. The sequence's length is at around 4-5).

I am wondering is there is a way to compute the probability of this sequence to be a subsequence of a "previously seen sequences"

---

I'll give another example that is probably easier to understand with a variation of the **hangman game**.

Let's assume you create a graph of letter's transition based on a subset of words from the dictionnary (50% of the dictionnary). I provides you some letters in order but not the gap in between (`rbiy`). Is there a way to compute how probable is this sequence to be a subset of an exiting word ? Here, it is a subset of the work `probability`.

Many thanks for any suggestions and support,

Nicolas